# C initializing a (very) large integer array with values corresponding to index

Tags: c, arrays

Edit3: Optimized by limiting the initialization of the array to only odd numbers. Thank you @Ronnie !

Edit2: Thank you all, seems as if there's nothing more I can do for this.

Edit: I know Python and Haskell are implemented in other languages and more or less perform the same operation I have bellow, and that the complied C code will beat them out any day. I'm just wondering if standard C (or any libraries) have built-in functions for doing this faster.

I'm implementing a prime sieve in C using Eratosthenes' algorithm and need to initialize an integer array of arbitrary size *n* from 0 to *n*. I know that in Python you could do:

```
integer_array = range(n)
```

and that's it. Or in Haskell:

```
integer_array = [1..n]
```

However, I can't seem to find an analogous method implemented in C. The solution I've come up with initializes the array and then iterates over it, assigning each value to the index at that point, but it feels incredibly inefficient.

```
int init_array()
{
    /* 
    * assigning upper_limit manually in function for now, will expand to take value for
    * upper_limit from the command line later.
    */
    int upper_limit = 100000000;
    int size = floor(upper_limit / 2) + 1;

    int *int_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    // debug macro, basically replaces assert(), disregard.    
    check(int_array != NULL, "Memory allocation error");

    int_array[0] = 0;
    int_array[1] = 2;

    int i;

    for(i = 2; i < size; i++) {
        int_array[i] = (i * 2) - 1;
    }

    // checking some arbitrary point in the array to make sure it assigned properly.
    // the value at any index 'i' should equal (i * 2) - 1 for i >= 2
    printf("%d\n", int_array[1000]);  // should equal 1999
    printf("%d\n", int_array[size-1]);  // should equal 99999999

    free(int_array);

    return 0;

error:
    return -1;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? (no, apparently there's not!)

Comment: Why would this be inefficient? This seems completely optimal. Any sensible compiler will have no difficulty figuring out what this code does and implementing it in whatever way is best for that platform.

Comment: It just seems as if there should be some way to initialize the array with the values from 0 to n faster. Since I'm looking at arrays of arbitrary size this could end up slowing down the algorithm, even when it's implemented in compiled C code.

Comment: Why would you think some other way would be faster? What could possibly be sub-optimal about this code? You've cleanly and clearly told the compiler what you want, what would prevent it from generating the most efficient code to achieve that effect?

Comment: How much faster than *O(n)* (i.e. linear time) do you think you can possibly initialize an array? You might as well ask how you can connect two points using something shorter than the straight line between them. Also, when it comes to optimizing don't go by how things "*feel*". Go by the numbers.

Comment: Excellent points from all, thank you very much. I suppose this is just as good as it gets.

Comment: You'd probably get more benefit by reducing the array by a factor of two and only storing odd numbers; you really don't need to process any of the even numbers except two itself.

Comment: True, I'll go ahead and do that.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize an array with integers from 1 to `n`? If you really want to speed up your sieve, focus on the algorithm, not on micro-benchmarks. All you need is to know if the number at index `i` has been sieved or not; you already know which number it is when you index it.

Comment: Which means you only need one bit for each odd number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a better algorithm is probably a better bet in terms of optimising the allocation:-

1. Halve the size int_array_ptr by taking advantage of the fact that
   you'll only need to test for odd numbers in the sieve
2. Run this through some wheel factorisation for numbers 3,5,7 to reduce the subsequent comparisons by 70%+

That should speed things up.

Comment: **Excellent**. This answer perfectly demonstrates the very important point that @Thilo made.

Answer (score 10):

> The solution I've come up with initializes the array and then iterates over it, assigning each value to the index at that point, but it feels incredibly inefficient.

You may be able to cut down on the number of lines of code, but I do not think this has anything to do with "efficiency".

While there is only one line of code in Haskell and Python, what happens under the hood is the same thing as your C code does (in the best case; it could perform much worse depending on how it is implemented).

There are standard library functions to fill an array with constant values (and they could conceivably perform better, although I would not bet on that), but this does not apply here.

Comment: The only minimal improvement I could see making a bit of sense is to compare with 0 instead of `size` in the loop. CPUs are better at that. I am doubtful if that makes a meaningful difference.

Comment: The Haskell and Python versions (well, Python 3) are actually O(1).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Really? How do they do that?

Comment: They don't create arrays.  The Haskell version creates a lazy list, and the Python version creates a "range object".

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I am assuming OP actually needs the array later. If the array can be removed completely, that would be best, of course.